# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{2.3cm}p{1.4cm}p{2.3cm}p{1.45cm}}
        \hline
        \bf p & \bf N & \bf $\|u-u_{h}\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}$ & \bf $L^{2}$ Rate & \bf $\|u-u_{h}\|_{H^{1}(0,1)}$ & \bf $H^{1}$ Rate\\
        \hline
        1  & 2  & $1.1735 \times 10^{-2}$ & \centering -- & $2.3671 \times 10^{-2}$ & \centering --\\
        -- & 4  & $3.0549 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.9416        & $1.1547 \times 10^{-2}$ & 1.0356\\
        -- & 8  & $7.4722 \times 10^{-4}$ & 2.0315        & $5.4262 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.0895\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

So I'm getting that error with the above code and I know it's because in the last column of the second row of entries (i.e. the first row with actual data), I have "centering --". I'm confused why that doesn't work though since it works for the 2nd row, 4th column entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need only a correction, here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{2.3cm}p{1.4cm}p{2.3cm}p{1.45cm}}
        \hline
        \bf p & \bf N & \bf $\|u-u_{h}\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}$ & \bf $L^{2}$ Rate & \bf $\|u-u_{h}\|_{H^{1}(0,1)}$ & \bf $H^{1}$ Rate\\
        \hline
 %       1  & 2  & $1.1735 \times 10^{-2}$ & \centering -- & $2.3671 \times 10^{-2}$ & \centering --\\
       1  & 2  & $1.1735 \times 10^{-2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ --} & $2.3671 \times 10^{-2}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ --}\\
        -- & 4  & $3.0549 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.9416        & $1.1547 \times 10^{-2}$ & 1.0356\\
        -- & 8  & $7.4722 \times 10^{-4}$ & 2.0315        & $5.4262 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.0895\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data are all homogeneous in columns as in the example you show, you can let TeX compute the column widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\toprule
\bfseries p & \bfseries N & $\|u-u_{h}\|_{L^{2}(0,1)}$ &
  \bfseries $L^{2}$ Rate & $\|u-u_{h}\|_{H^{1}(0,1)}$ & \bfseries $H^{1}$ Rate\\
\midrule
1  & 2  & $1.1735 \times 10^{-2}$ & --      & $2.3671 \times 10^{-2}$ & -- \\
-- & 4  & $3.0549 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.9416  & $1.1547 \times 10^{-2}$ & 1.0356\\
-- & 8  & $7.4722 \times 10^{-4}$ & 2.0315  & $5.4262 \times 10^{-3}$ & 1.0895\\
\toprule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Use `\centering` and not the `center` environment inside `table`; also use `\bfseries` and not `\bf` that's obsolete.

[image]

---

The problem was due to the fact that `\centering` changes the meaning of `\\` so the `\\` after it wasn't interpreted as a "end of row".

Don't worry about using `\centering` as advised, because `tabular` restores the meaning of `\\` to the right thing. The problem is in using `\centering` *inside* a `tabular`.

Comment: @barbara-beeton Just curious and I have some spare time:-). When you edit an answer or a question, do you keep the uppercase letters or do you turn them into lowercase?

Comment: @null -- when i edit on tex.sx, if i'm correcting an error that involves an incorrect case (for example, `\LaTex`, which should be `\LaTeX` unless the definition of the "unusual" form is present in the quesion or answer), i would change it to the correct form.  but i try not to make any changes unless it's for accuracy or searchability.  for a current question, if it doesn't make sense, but i can guess what it's likely to mean, i'll usually make a comment, not an edit, and ask for the op to follow up.

Comment: I knew that already. Sorry for wasting your time:-)